# Yii 1.1.16 : components folder is not accessible all over the application in Ubuntu

Tags: php, yii

The error I'm getting is:

`include(widgetHomeMenu.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

same for all other widget views I'm rendering on other pages.

The file is in my components directory. I guess the directory is not accessible because the file exists there. Plus I've given permission to all the files in `/var/www`.

Also in my `config.php` file, there is:

```
// autoloading model and component classes
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
),
```

So, I guess the config is loading components as well.

Not sure where is the problem exactly. No problems with case sensitivity, its correct and the filename is correct as well. The application is working flawlessly on several Windows PC using xampp.

Will be thankful for any help.

Comment: Try to move `widgetHomeMenu.php` to `extensions` folder and check again. Also add `'application.extensions.*'` inside `import` array.

Comment: can't move files because there are other developers who are working on it and the site is working perfectly on their systems.

Comment: if you are using import already , you do not need to include the file by its name. Including the file requires proper path . If the classname is same as the file name, simply use `$w = new widgetHomeMenu()` and so on..

Comment: I'm doing `$this->widget('widgetHomeMenu');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It was ultimately related to case sensitivity even though I mentioned above that there was no such problem.

I was loading the widget like this:

```
<?php $this->widget('widgetDashboardMenu');?>
```

where I thought that `widgetDashboardMenu` was the name of the view that was about to render (my bad). This was actually the controller inside components named `WidgetDashboardMenu` which then loaded `widgetDashboardMenu`.

So, changing `w` to `W` solved the problem for me.

```
<?php $this->widget('WidgetDashboardMenu');?>
```

Comment: Case sensitivity is also an issue for table names and models. Bit me once.